# How to count the number of substrings that can be generated from a given string

Tags: combinatorics

Given an input string, e.g. "ABC" with input size of n, how can I count the number of possible substrings that can be generated from it? I.e. these are valid substrings:

```
A
AB
ABC
B
BC
C
```

and for string "AB":

```
A
AB
B
```

What is the general formula to calculate the number of substrings? I am going to assume no duplicate letters for now to make things simpler.

Comment: Hint: Let the string be $a_1a_2\dots a_n$, where the $a_i$ are distinct. How many substrings begin with $a_1$? How many begin with $a_2$?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine periods or underscores inbetween and to the left and right of each letter.

$$.A.B.C.$$

Pick two of these periods.  The left period will denote the beginning of the substring and the right period will denote the end of the substring.

$$.A\color{red}{\bullet}B.C\color{red}{\bullet}\mapsto BC$$

With a string of length $n$ with all letters different, there will be $\binom{n+1}{2} = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$ possible substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Given an string of length $n$, there are

$n$ substrings of length $1$,

$n-1$ substrings of length $2$,

$n-2$ substrings of length $3$,

$\dots$

$1$ substring of length $n$.

So the answer is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$